# Абсолютный путь к папке на уровень выше

Tags: php

Есть главная папка с проектом в которой находится папка конфига, в конфиге есть php файл, в котором я ищу абсолютный путь к этой папке так:

`define('CONFIG_ROOT', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', getcwd()));`

**Как я могу используя такой подход найти путь к папке, которая на уровень выше?**

спасибо!

Comment: `./` - текущий каталог, `../` - родительский каталог

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) уже придуман.

Comment: @u_mulder если автору вопроса нужен dirname - значит я неверно понял его вопрос =) кому как удобней, но лично мне получить доступ из скрипта к папке "на уровень выше" удобней именно через `../`, это просто и это понятно. `../images/../images/../........`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да, это то понятно, просто нужен абсолютный путь к папке на уровень выше, вариант с ../ это относительный)

Comment: уж что-что а cwd вам точно лучше избегать

Comment: @Евгений для каких целей вам понадобился абсолютный путь?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле путь вида `/home/www/site/html/../file.php` является вполне себе абсолютным. Поскольку строится от корня диска. Соответственно, **нет проблемы** воспользоваться советом из  комментария и добавить `'/..'` к любому пути, чтобы получить путь к папке на уровень выше. Если к наличию элемента .. в пути есть претензии эстетического плана, то есть функция `realpath()` которая служит для превращения пути с точками в канонический абсолютный путь.

Но более красивым будет другой вариант, функция `dirname()`, которая попросту отнимает от текущей строки вида `/one/two/three` последний элемент. То есть делает ровно то, что требуется - возвращает путь к каталогу на один уровень выше.

Отдельно хочу заметить, что использованный в вопросе код довольно странный, и может привести к непредсказуемым результатам. Так что я бы получал путь к текущему файлу через константу `__DIR__`, а путь к папке выше, соответственно -

```
define('CONFIG_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('UPPER_DIR', dirname(CONFIG_ROOT));
```

каковой код и можно рекомендовать в качестве ответа на вопрос